# How to target match input on onload function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck with the function which have to do if input has class 'inerror' then div next to it should appear, but when I am running the function it is displaying all the div. Is there is solution for it without using each function. here is my code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
if($('input').hasClass('inerror')){
$('input', this).next().show();
} 
})
</script>
<style>
.inerror{border:solid 1px #F00}
.error{ display:none}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="submit" />
<div class="error">error</div> <br />
<input type="button" value="submit" />
<div class="error">error</div> <br />
<input type="button" class="inerror"  value="submit"/>
<div class="error">error</div> <br />
<input type="button" value="submit"/>
<div class="error">error</div> <br />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input', this).next().show()
```

This matches the next sibling of *all* `<input>` elements, regardless of the check before it.

Try this instead:

```
$("input.inerror").next().show();
```